How to Prevent Slowdowns When Creating Daily Indexes in ElasticSearch?
I have an index for each of our clients in ElasticSearch. Each client sends a large amount of information. Each client also has a different retention period for the information saved. Therefore, I am saving the information in daily indexes per client. This allows me to delete the indexes daily once the retention period has passed.
The issue is that at midnight, when the new indexes are created, there is a substantial slowdown in ElasticSearch, causing all my servers to be under pressure. What should I do to fix this issue?

The index creation process is usually fast and do not add huge pressure to the cluster unless you create +100 shards per index or you create +100 indices at the same time. I need more context to answer your question properly. Can you share more about your cluster.

How many shards and indices do you have?
How many nodes do you have?
How big is your cluster state?
How many fields do you have in one index?
If any of the above is too much you should optimize it.


I've 8 nodes. 1800 indices when each day I create around 200 indices. Each index has a primary and a replica. Some indices are small when others are very big. It all depends on each client. The biggest client has more than 20 GB for each index (in this case they have 5p and 1r). There are about 30 fields.

How do you create/rollover indices? Is it possible to create indices gradually? In other words Is instead of creating the 200 index at the the same time like 00:00, can you create between 00:00 and 00:15? If you are using ILM rollover what is the condition to rollover, are there too small shards like shards less than 1 GB?

I'm getting monitoring information for each client. When the information is entered I'm creating the index if it is a new day. The issue is that I'm getting cpu pressure for more than an hour each night at midnight.
There are too small shards but I can't know it in advance. I've it all depends on the amount of monitoring data that I get

High CPU usage reason can be vary. It can be because of too many index creation at the same time like we talked, or too many snapshot at the same time, or scheduled heavy request at the middle of the night... You should find the root cause by monitoring your cluster.
